# Create DataJPATest with 2 parallel transactions to simulate update lock timeout

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions, locking

I would like to test my application when two simultaneous updates occured and manage lockTimeoutException.

I have my entity :

```
@Entity(name = "wallet")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WalletEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private @NonNull String name;
    private @NonNull Integer walletBalance;
}
```

I have my repository

```
public interface WalletRepository extends JpaRepository<WalletEntity, Long> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query("SELECT entity FROM wallet entity WHERE entity.id = :id")
    WalletEntity findByIdForLock(@Param("id") Long id);


    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE wallet SET walletBalance = :value WHERE id = :id")
    void updateBalance(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("value") Long value);

    @Nullable
    WalletEntity findByName(@NonNull final String name);
}
```

Here is my test (Kotlin)

```
@SpringBootTest
open class TestUpdateConcurrencyThread {


    @Autowired
    protected lateinit var repository: WalletRepository

    @Test
    fun `thread`() {
        repository.save(
            WalletEntity.builder()
                .name("my wallet")
                .walletBalance(0)
                .build()
        )

        val wallet = repository.findByName("my wallet");

        executeActionsInThread(
            listOf(
                { doUpdateThread(wallet!!.id, 10) },
                { doUpdateThread(wallet!!.id, -20) },
            )
        )

        assertEquals(-10, repository.findByUuid(wallet!!.uuid)?.walletBalance)
        // we can count doUpdate call, if timeout should be 3 times call
    }

    fun executeActionsInThread(actions: List<() -> Unit>) {
        val executor: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(actions.size)

        for (action in actions) {
            executor.execute { action() }
        }

        executor.shutdown()
        assertTrue(executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
    }

    @Transactional
    open fun doUpdateThread(walletId: Long, value: Long) {
            val wallet = repository.findByIdForLock(walletId) // Exception comes from here
            println("\nUpdate $value: lock enabled $wallet\n")
            println("\nUpdate $value: before update\n")
            repository.updateBalance(walletId, wallet.walletBalance + value);
            println("\nUpdate $value: after update\n")
            println("\nUpdate $value: end delay\n")
            Thread.sleep(3000)
    }


}
```

I have the following error `Query requires transaction be in progress, but no transaction is known to be in progress` even if there is a @Transactional.

Why the transaction is not initialized ?
Is the correct way to test my use case ?

PS : I test over PostgreSQL and added `SET lock_timeout TO '2s'` to have a lock timeout...

Here is the full stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-2" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Query requires transaction be in progress, but no transaction is known to be in progress
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:400)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:234)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:400)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:234)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy169.findByIdForLock(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy169.findByIdForLock(Unknown Source)
    at eu.centralpay.core_banking.TestUpdateConcurrencyThread.doUpdateThread(TestUpdateConcurrencyThread.kt:64)
...
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Query requires transaction be in progress, but no transaction is known to be in progress
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:857)
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Query requires transaction be in progress, but no transaction is known to be in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.prepareForQueryExecution(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.beforeQuery(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.prepareForQueryExecution(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.beforeQuery(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:388)
2023-12-21 14:27:13,749 TRACE # [:@] o.s.t.i.TransactionAspectSupport (TransactionAspectSupport.java:638    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:473)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:405)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy172.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:223)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:405)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy172.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:223)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    ... 14 more
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: I tried different way (entityManager creation from entityManagerFactory and then create transaction, entityManager injection and then transaction initiliatisation, ...)